# Why is induced current through an inductor more when switch is put off than when the switch is put on?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

This problem I saw somewhere got me thinking. I thought very hard about this but couldn't get to any conclusion. (here opened and closed are verbs, i mean when the current is flowing in the circuit and we cut the key off, its opened, and when there is no current in the circuit and we switch it on, its closed.)

Comment: This question makes no sense outside the context of some particular circuit. You need to share what circuit you are considering in order for anybody to be able to answer this.

Comment: For example, if the switch is connected in series with the inductor, then the premise is simply not true. If the switch is open, then no current can flow through the inductor, while when the switch is closed, possibly some current will flow through the inductor, which is the opposite result from what you supposed.

Comment: Do you instead mean "induced voltage"?

Comment: @ThePhoton I have edited the post for clarifying the question.

Comment: It still makes no sense. Why do you think there is more current when the switch is opened than when it is closed?

Comment: because its a question of HC Verma (I suppose you know the book?)

Comment: I presume you're talking about transient currents. I'm sure H. C. Verma would have a specific kind of switch in mind that leads to higher transient currents during opening than when closing; can you please give a circuit and describe the kind of switch.

Comment: no no, this is a short answer question, just for testing the thoroughness in concepts and tinkering one's grey matter. There are no circuits here. The question is out of the chapter Electromagnetic induction(Elementary, I am in 12th Standard, India)

Comment: and why i m getting downvotes I don't understand. I mean that's a good question isn't it?

Comment: no answers yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine a circuit consisting of a battery, a wire, a switch, and an inductor, all in series. For "resistor" you could simply sum the internal resistance of battery and wire - it doesn't really matter (I just don't like "unrealistic" circuits for simple explanations).

When you close the switch, current will attempt to flow. The most current that could flow (if the inductor were a perfect conductor) is $I_0=\frac{V}{R}$, but the inductor will try to resist the change in current and therefore generate a reverse e.m.f. that is initially no greater than V, the voltage of the battery (because when it reaches that value, there is no force left to drive current).

When the switch is opened, the current through the inductor attempts to go to zero "in an instant". Unfortunately, just generating a back e.m.f. of V will not be sufficient to stop the current change - the circuit is broken, and with an infinite resistance in the loop you need an infinite back e.m.f. to keep the current flowing.

In reality there will be a little bit of stray capacitance in any inductor (if only the turn-to-turn capacitance); that acts to create a "short circuit" for the current, so the change in current through the inductor when the switch is opened is not infinite, and a finite voltage spike ensues.

But either way, the back e.m.f. is indeed greater when the switch is opened than when it's closed, because the circuit impedance is greater.